# Map one numpy array on to another on condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have three arrays, looking for final output:

```
a = (array(['Call', 'Call', 'Call', 'Call', 'NoCall', 'Call', 'NoCall', 'Call']))

b      = (array(['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']))
c      = (array(['2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2']))
output = (array(['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1']))
```

This I tried `"for"` loop, it didnt replace values. These are numpy (long)  arrays.  I was thinking of using itertools or numpy.map?? If element in `a ="NoCall"`, change value in b from 1 to 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> np.where(a=='Call', b, c)
array([u'1', u'1', u'1', u'1', u'2', u'1', u'2', u'1'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: @Merlin: Creating a new array.

Comment: @Merlin: In-place replacement of what?  You have three arrays there.  Which one do you want to modify?